# Nodejs Pagination and Search

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Hi I am implementing a Pagination and Search on the server side with the following code below. It works for me however with a small bug.

For example: 
page 1: user1, user2, user3 
page 2: user4, user5, user6

The whole db contains 6 users, but when i try to do a filter by user5, if i am on page 1 it wont be able to search for user5, only when i go to page2, will user5 appear. i would like to do a filter first and slice base on the filter but am facing difficulties.

do appreciate help thanks

```
router.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let query = User.find();

    const filter = req.query;
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
    const pageSize = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10;
    const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const total = await User.countDocuments();
    const pages = Math.ceil(total / pageSize);

    if (page > pages) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "No page found",
      });
    }

    result = await query.skip(skip).limit(pageSize);
    const filtered = result.filter(target => {
      if (filter.filter === "") {
        return target;
      }
      else if (target.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.filter)){
        return target;
      }
      else if (target.email.toLowerCase().includes(filter.filter)){
        return target;
      }
    })
    
    res.json({
      status: "success",
      filter,
      count: result.length,
      page,
      pages,
      data: filtered
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Server Error",
    });
  }
});
```

[it should return one user here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNc0B.png)

[it only returns that user in page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luVP3.png)

I am expecting that the user be return no matter where it is in the pages.

Comment: The `filter` callback should return a boolean value if that current element should be included in the result array, and the `slice` should be on the returned filtered array. Can you walk us through the filtering/slicing code/logic and what you are wanting/expecting to occur?

Comment: @DrewReese i am expecting a global search with pagination. meaning if search results exceeds limit of 10, it will break into pages. and if i were to search for a user, it shuld return me all results despite being in other pages. sorry if i am unclear
<br>
i tried to slice target here but it returns a target.slice not a function error

Comment: No, I meant more start at `const filter = req.query;` or `result = await query.skip(skip).limit(pageSize);` and walk us through the code and what you are wanting/expecting it to do.

Comment: @DrewReese at the start it sets like a few parameters from the api calls. filter gets the values it wants from for example: localhost:5000/users/?filter=user5. so it should get user5 from the db. but right now since i have paginated the web localhost:5000/users/?filter=&page=2, it will only return user5 if user5 is in page 2. i have added a few photos

Comment: So is the question then more "how to recompute an adjust page when the search value isn't on the page requested"?

Comment: @DrewReese i guess that could work as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the filter, you can use the  $regex operator instead of using the filter function. and use the HTTP post method for taking input from the request body instead of get.

```
router.route('/').post(async (req, res) => {    
 try {
    const filter = req.body.query;
    let where = {};
    if (filter.name) {
        where.name = { $regex: filter.name, $options: "i" }
    }
    let query = User.find(where);
    const page = parseInt(req.body.page) || 1;
    const pageSize = parseInt(req.body.limit) || 10;
    const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const total = await User.countDocuments(where);
    const pages = Math.ceil(total / pageSize);

    if (page > pages) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            status: "fail",
            message: "No page found",
        });
    }
    result = await query.skip(skip).limit(pageSize);
    res.json({
        status: "success",
        filter,
        count: result.length,
        page,
        pages,
        data: result
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({
        status: "error",
        message: "Server Error",
    });
  }
 });
```

request body for pagination -

```
{
  "query":{"name":"jo"}
  "page":1,
  "limit":3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/listProducts',auth, (req, res) => {
    
    let perPage = 3
    let page = req.query.page || 1
    let searchKeyword = req.query.search;

    let searchObj = {};
    if (searchKeyword) {
        searchObj = /^(?:\d*\.\d{1,2}|\d+)$/.test(searchKeyword)
          ? {
              $or: [{ discount: searchKeyword }, { price: searchKeyword }],
            }
          : { name: new RegExp(`${searchKeyword.toString().trim()}`, 'i') };
      }
    // tmpSearch = { name: new RegExp(search, 'i') }
      
    products
        .find(searchObj)
        .sort({ name: 1 })
        .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .exec(function (err, docs) {
            products.count(searchObj).exec(function (err, count) {
                res.render('listProducts', {
                    search: searchKeyword,
                    quotes: docs,
                    current: page,
                    pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage)
                })
            })
        })

});




        <table class="table table-striped table-sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Discription</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%for (let i=0; i < quotes.length; i++) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%=i+1%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= quotes[i].name %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $<%= quotes[i].price %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= quotes[i].discount %>%
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= quotes[i].quantity %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= quotes[i].discription %>
                        </td>
                        <td><img src="image/<%= quotes[i].file %>" width="50px" height="50px"></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/edit/<%=quotes[i]._id%>"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"
                                    aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/delete/<%=quotes[i].id %>"
                                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"><i
                                    class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/views/<%=quotes[i].id %>">views</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <% if (pages> 0) { %>
            <ul class="pagination text-center">
                <% if (current==1) { %>
                    <li class="disabled"><a>First</a></li>
                 <% } else { %>
                    <li><a href="/listProducts?page=1">First</a></li>
         <% } %>
         <% var i=(Number(current)> 5 ? Number(current) - 4 : 1) %>
                <% if (i !==1) { %>
                    <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
                <% } %>
        <% for (; i <=(Number(current) + 4) && i <=pages; i++) { %>
                <% if (i==current) { %>
                    <li class="active"><a><%= i %></a></li>
                <% } else { %>
                    <li><a href="/listProducts?page=<%= i %>"> <%= i %></a></li>
                <% } %>
                <% if (i==Number(current) + 4 && i < pages) { %>
                    <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>
                <% } %>
        <% } %>
                <% if (current==pages) { %>
                   <li class="disabled"><a>Last</a></li>
                <% } else { %>
                   <li><a href="/listProducts?page=<%= pages %>">Last</a> </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
            <% } %>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).